# how to call function of controller in cakephp framework with default function?

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, routes

i am new comer for cakephp framework. i can not call functions of controller.
 Controller-

```
class PagesController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Pages';
    public $uses = array();

    public function display() {
        $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
    }

    public function register() {
        $this->set('fdf', 'chandan');
        $this->render('home1');
    }
}
```

But i am calling display(). but i am not calling register(). my routes.php file like-

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

Please help me. how to call controller function from view in cakephp.
and what setting have to done for it ?.

Comment: maybe you should read up on some basics of MVC design patterns

Comment: The view doesnt call controller functions. The dispatcher calls the controller which renders the view

Comment: i have worked on codeigniter. where we can write like for call <a href="print site_url('controller_name/fun_name');".

Comment: What controller are you working in? You need to explain your code better

Comment: PagesController is working

Comment: [Start with the beginning](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html#getting-started) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A few points I would make, the routes file is for defining custom slugs/url, take a look at your first route definition here:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

This is saying that "www.mysite.com/" should link to the controller pages, the action display and pass the first parameter as home.

This can be accessed by doing *"www.mysite.com/pages/display/home"* in short - but using "/" as a route is tidier. The general rule is *"www.mysite.com/controller/action/param1/param2/etc.."*

So following this logic you would access your new action method like such:
**"www.mysite.com/pages/register"**

That being said... When using MVC you should really follow the conventions set out, if you're going to create a register method you should really contain it within a controller which deals with user accounts i.e. "UsersController" - "www.mysite.com/users/register"

Also, you shouldn't really need to use $this->render() unless you have to render a separate view under special conditions.

To sum up, contain all actions within a relevant controller (i.e. www.mysite.com/users/login and www.mysite.com/users/register), never directly specify $this->render unless you really need to render something other than the default (/users/register.ctp would be the default for www.mysite.com/users/register) and routes are used to create tidier or custom urls.

I would highly recommend you read and follow the blog tutorial to grasp these concepts.